# Data receiving from Bluetooth Low Energy device in android is very slow

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on one android application which is based on BLE Fitness band.we have 3 type of fitness band.data receiving from band is proper but one issue that receiving data from one ble device taking to much time in seconds.and other two bands are working properly and receiving data quickly from that band.if i check that band with another app which is in play store its receiving data very quickly so there is no issue of band.so please can anyone knows how to solve this issue which method of ble is required? how to write code for that or can any one knows any link to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to increase the MTU by requesting a bigger one:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestMtu(int)

However this API was introduced with Android 5.0 and you need to check the OS version before calling it.